# How to Log Machine Learning with Azure Functions

Tags: python, machine-learning, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-durable-functions

I am planning to implement machine learning with Durable functions in Azure Functions.

Machine learning requires logging the learning steps, should I log to Blob storage in Azure Functions?

Please let me know how to log and the code to do so.

I've included the entire code and the code for the part in question

```
import  azure.functions  as  func
import  azure.durable_functions  as  df
import  pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing  # dataset
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import pytorch_lightning as pl
from pytorch_lightning.loggers import CSVLogger
from torchvision import transforms, datasets
from torchmetrics.functional import accuracy

class Net(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=3, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.bn = nn.BatchNorm2d(3)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(588, 10) 

    def forward(self, x):
        h = self.conv(x)
        h = F.relu(h)
        h = self.bn(h)
        h = F.max_pool2d(h, kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        h = h.view(-1, 588)
        h = self.fc(h)
        return h
    
    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, t = batch
        y = self(x)
        loss = F.cross_entropy(y, t)
        train_acc = accuracy(y.argmax(dim=-1), t, task='multiclass', num_classes=10, top_k=1)
        self.log('train_loss', loss, on_step=True, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        self.log('train_acc', train_acc, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        return loss
    
    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, t = batch
        y = self(x)
        loss = F.cross_entropy(y, t)
        val_acc = accuracy(y.argmax(dim=-1), t, task='multiclass', num_classes=10, top_k=1)
        self.log('val_loss', loss, on_step=False, on_epoch=True)
        self.log('val_acc', val_acc, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        return loss
    
    def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, t = batch
        y = self(x)
        loss = F.cross_entropy(y, t)
        test_acc = accuracy(y.argmax(dim=-1), t, task='multiclass', num_classes=10, top_k=1)
        self.log('test_loss', loss, on_step=False, on_epoch=True)
        self.log('test_acc', test_acc, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        return loss
    
    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=0.01)
        return optimizer

app  =  df.DFApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)  
@app.route(route="orchestrators/client_function")
@app.durable_client_input(client_name="client")
async  def  client_function(req: func.HttpRequest, client: df.DurableOrchestrationClient) -> func.HttpResponse:
    instance_id  =  await  client.start_new("orchestrator", None, {})
    await  client.wait_for_completion_or_create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
    return client.create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)

### orchestrator function ###
@app.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
def orchestrator(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext) -> str:
    result = yield context.call_activity("image", '')
    return "compleated"

### activity function ###
@app.blob_output(arg_name="outputblob", path="newblob/test.txt", connection="BlobStorageConnection")
@app.activity_trigger(input_name="blank")
def image(blank: str, outputblob: func.Out[str]):

    # Data Set Conversion
    transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()])
    train_val = datasets.MNIST('./', train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
    test = datasets.MNIST('./', train=False, download=True, transform=transform)

    # Split into train and val
    n_train,n_val = 50000, 10000
    torch.manual_seed(0)
    train, val = torch.utils.data.random_split(train_val, [n_train, n_val])
    
    # Define Data Loader
　　 batch_size = 256
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, drop_last=True)
    val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val, batch_size=batch_size)
    test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test, batch_size=batch_size)

    # Performing Learning
    net = Net()
    logger = CSVLogger(save_dir='logs', name='my_exp')
    trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=5, deterministic=True, logger=logger)
    trainer.fit(net, train_loader, val_loader)

    # Evaluated with test data
    results = trainer.test(dataloaders=test_loader)
    return str(results)
```

I don't know where to log the learning steps, the code.

```
# Performing Learning
net = Net()
logger = CSVLogger(save_dir='logs', name='my_exp')
trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=5, deterministic=True, logger=logger)
trainer.fit(net, train_loader, val_loader)
```

Where and how do I write the epoch logs?

Answer (score -1):

You can use Blob Storage for logging the learning steps, especially when you have larger logs.

You can stream them directly to Azure Blob Storage. You'll have to create a custom logger to do this:

```py
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
from pytorch_lightning.loggers import LightningLoggerBase
from pytorch_lightning.utilities import rank_zero_only

class AzureBlobLogger(LightningLoggerBase):

    def __init__(self, container_name, blob_name_prefix, connection_string):
        super().__init__()
        self.container_name = container_name
        self.blob_name_prefix = blob_name_prefix
        self.blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
        self.container_client = self.blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
        if not self.container_client.exists():
            self.container_client.create_container()

    @rank_zero_only
    def log_metrics(self, metrics, step):
        blob_name = f"{self.blob_name_prefix}_step_{step}.csv"
        blob_client = self.blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=self.container_name, blob=blob_name)
        csv_content = ",".join([f"{k},{v}" for k, v in metrics.items()])
        blob_client.upload_blob(csv_content, overwrite=True)

    @rank_zero_only
    def log_hyperparams(self, params):
        # Implement if needed
        pass

    # Implement other necessary functions...
```

Now you can update your code to use AzureBlobLogger

```py
def image(blank: str, outputblob: func.Out[str]):
    # ... [rest of your code]

    # Performing Learning
    net = Net()
    azure_logger = AzureBlobLogger(
        container_name="your_container_name",
        blob_name_prefix="your_desired_prefix",
        connection_string="YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING"
    )
    trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=5, deterministic=True, logger=azure_logger)
    trainer.fit(net, train_loader, val_loader)

    # Evaluated with test data
    results = trainer.test(dataloaders=test_loader)
    return str(results)
```

Comment: When I used that code, I got the following error. [ Orchestrator function 'orchestrator' failed: Activity function 'origin_image' failed:  OSError: [Errno 38] Function not implemented: '/home/site/wwwroot/AzureBlobLogger'  ]